# magento sort by price not working fine

Tags: magento-1.9, price, sort

**sort by price** is not working in magento 1.9

my site has just configurable products only .
when i checked code it was using below code to load products

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

so i though of temporary fix (below code) , but that code work fine for just single page , issue is still there when user navigates to next page. so i need way to fix this bug . Does any one have idea page where getLoadedProductCollection is defined . So i can add sort there to fix issue

```
foreach($_productCollection as $mprod){
    $products=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->loadByAttribute('sku',$mprod->getSku());
    $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product = $obj->load($products->getData('default_configuration_id')); echo " ";
    $mysortprice[(int)$product->getPrice()] =  $mprod;
}
$sortorder = (string)$this->getRequest()->getParam('dir');
$sorttype = (string)$this->getRequest()->getParam('order');

if($sortorder=='asc' && $sorttype=='price'){
    ksort($mysortprice);
}else if($sortorder=='desc' && $sorttype=='price'){
        krsort($mysortprice);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Sorting by price should work perfectly for any kind of products if you have Price Attribute chosed if Available Sort Options (on Category edit page) and if you have Price Index built well.

Just try to add "`?dir=desc&order=price`" to your category url and see if it will change sorting

2) But if you would like to apply your custom sorting anyway - you can use Observer method, which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7679942/4945184)

3) But, call for "`loadByAttribute`"  for all products in the collection is very heavy. 
Instead of it you need to use next code:

```
$products = $observer->getCollection();
$products->addFinalPrice();
$products->getSelect()
    ->order('price_index.final_price', 'asc');
```

Comment: i am using configurable products and magento's default sort by price seems not fine i had done indexing and all

Comment: You can also check "Admin - Catalog - Edit Attributes - Price" attribute. Use for sorting option should be enabled like here https://monosnap.com/file/4c0vkoKohTmtlvEq8AbqrbwLSVDb3i#

Comment: But anyway - Price sorting should work by default. Maybe some third party extension blocking or broke this sorting. If you can share an access to admin panel - I can review it more detailed

Comment: can i have ur email or skype

Comment: pinged u on skype check if u can help